# Is there a way to match ( ) brackets in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I trying to match the following using regular expression but I struggling in matching the round bracket.

[??(Z)Z-axis Down Position Stroke]

Can anyone kindly advise ?

My Current expression as shown.
`[[][[a-zA-Z0-9_?. - ]{1,30}[]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a backslash `\` before any character to escape it. Try this regex:

`\[\?\?\(Z\)Z-axis Down Position Stroke\]`

When writing regex, I find regex101.com to be really helpful. It's a free website that evaluates your regex and lets you specify test cases etc, then breaks those down and tells you about the various matching conditions in them. Worth a look if you're learning regular expressions.

Edit: Also, it's necessary to escape the brackets, parentheses, and question marks because those all have special meaning in regex.